# Property of Homology: group isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

I have this proposition, but I don't understand how they use the axiom 5, since in the axiom 5; $f,g: (X,A)\rightarrow (Y,B)$ and in the theorem we have $f:(X,A)\rightarrow (Y,B)$, $g:(Y,B)\rightarrow (X,A)$?

[image]

And the axiom 5 is:

[image]

Comment: Its obvious, just use functoriality

Comment: functoriality is only used to say that $f_*\circ g_*=id_{H_k(Y,B)}$ and $g_*\circ f_*=id_{H_k(X,A)}$

Comment: how to use axiom 5?

Comment: do you know that these equations mean that $f_\ast$ and $g_\ast$ are inverse to one another and hence isomorphisms?

Comment: so where is used axiom 5 ?

Comment: this is hardly worth answering, did you read the proof? he even says when he uses the axiom

Comment: ah ok axiom 5 is used for $f\circ g$ and $id$ not for $f$ and $g$ right ?

Comment: please stop trolling, I won't answer your questions anymore

Comment: but it is right i don't ask you to write the answer why you do this just say yes if you dont want to answer i dont oblige you

Comment: yes of course it is true and what i am saying is that if this is not obvious to you then you should read something more elementary!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $f$ and $g$ appearing in the proof are not the same as the $f$ and $g$ appearing in the axiom. We have $g\circ f\sim\mbox{Id}_{X,A}\colon (X,A)\to (X,A)$ and so axiom $5$ implies that $(g\circ f)_*=(\mbox{Id}_{X,A})_*$, the other axioms then give us that $(g\circ f)_*=g_*\circ f_*$ by funtoriality, and $(\mbox{Id}_{X,A})_*=\mbox{Id}_{H_k(X,A)}$ also by functoriality. Similarly for $f\circ g$. The proof is completed by using the fact that an isomorphism is defined to be an arrow which has another arrow acting as a right and left inverse, in this case $g_*$ is the right and left inverse of $f_*$.